# How to calculate probabilities if it is given $p = 70\%$ and $n = 10$?

Tags: probability, statistics

It is given a random variable $X$, which is binomially distributed, the probability of occurrence is $p = 70\%$ and $n = 10$.
It is given $E = \{X = 0\} \cup \{X = 6\}$.

Calculate:

$P(E)=?$ (Solution: $\frac{2001268539}{10000000000}$)

$P(X=3)=?$ (Solution: $\frac{2250423}{250000000}$)

Can someone give me some directions? I don't know which formula I should use so I can use all given information? I wrote correct answers too.

Comment: Recall $P(X=a) = {n\choose a} p^a(1-p)^{n-a}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P[E]=P[X=0 \textrm{ or } X=6] = P[X=0] + P[X=6]$$

You can use the formula that Adam Hughes gave in his comment to evaluate these quantities.